# Webpack-dev-server historyApiFallback rewriting subdomains

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I am creating a React app consisting of multiple independent subpages.
I currently have a independent 'landing page', 'menus page' and a 'menu page' (the latter two at some point might become one). I am using webpack to bundle my page and the webpack dev server for local development.
The menu page is using react-router to be able to navigate around.
Here is my webpack setup for better understanding:

```
{
  entry: {
    menus: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "client", "menus.jsx"),
    landing: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "client", "landing.jsx"),
    menu: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "client", "menu.jsx"),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000",
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      verbose: true,
      index: "/landing.html",
      rewrites: [
        { from: /^\/menus/, to: "/menus.html" },
        { from: /^\/menu/, to: "/menu.html" },
        { from: /^\/menu\//, to: "/menu.html" },
      ],
    },
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:8080",
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputDirectory]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/client/index.html",
      chunks: ["menus"],
      filename: "menus.html",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/client/index.html",
      chunks: ["landing"],
      filename: "landing.html",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/client/index.html",
      chunks: ["menu"],
      filename: "menu.html",
    }),
  ],
}
```

My problem is that when I navigate to `/menu/orders` the historyApiFallback shows me the following logs:

```
Rewriting GET /menu/preview to /menu.html
Rewriting GET /menu/menu.bundle.js to /menu.html
```

The first rewrite is what I'd expect, however the second one is confusing to me. Firstly why is it trying to get `/menu/menu.bundle.js`? Secondly why is it rewriting the route if I have a "." in the route?
Finally how can I just make it work so that `/menu/preview` works exactly the same as `/menu`?

Here is my ./src/client/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Locameal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and the `./src/client/menu.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Menu from "./views/Menu";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Menu />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: can you post your `./src/client/index.html` ?

Comment: updates with the index and the menu files @udnisap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try adding

```
output: {
  publicPath: "/",
}
```

to your webpack config.

See [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/issues/205#issuecomment-315847782) answer for more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a regex so that all routes with `menu/*` are redirected to menu.html so that it doesn't try to resolve the bundle from `/menu/` when you are at `/menu/preview`

```
{ from: /^\/menu\/.*$/, to: "/menu.html" }
```

Check the documentation of [`connect-history-api-fallback`](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) for more details